# Sending context with request, and {% if %} not working properly

Tags: django

I have a problem trying to figure out why below will render an html page showing 'hi' and 1, instead of just 1.

views method.

```
def index(request):

    context = {
               'test' : 1,
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

template html. Rendering index.html will show both 'hi' and 1. But there's no user in context, so why is the if user going through?

```
    {% if user %}
        <h1>hi</h1>
    {% endif %}

    {% if test %}
        <h1>{{ test }}</h1>
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is Django's builtin context processor called [`django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth). It is enabled by default which means an `auth.User` object representing the currently logged-in user is sent to all templates with the name `user` automatically.

From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext):

> The **context_processors** option is a list of callables – called context processors – that take a request object as their argument and return a dictionary of items to be merged into the context. 
>   In the default generated settings file, the default template engine contains the following context processors:

```
[
    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
    'django.template.context_processors.request',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. :)

Answer (score 1):

if there is a user logged in django will create a  AUTH_USER_MODEL representing the currently logged-in user. Also from the request object you can access the user model without specifying context. For example if a user is logged in you can do request.user.username and the username will appear in the template.